# Query many-to-many relationships with extra columns using typeOrm

Tags: database, many-to-many, backend, typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

Using typeorm and trying to figure out how to query many-to-many relationships, i have two tables :

**product**(id,name...etc) <---many-to-many---> **stash**(id,name...etc)

 **the join table has two additional columns: expirationDate and quantity**

 I have already setp the relationships :

```js
@Entity('stash')
export class Stash {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id?: number;

    @Column("text")
    name!: string;

    @OneToMany(type => productStash, ps => ps.stash)
    public productStashes?: Relation<ProductStash[]>;
    
}
```

```js
@Entity('product')
export class Product {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id?: number;

    @Column("text")
    name!: string;

    @OneToMany(type => productStash, ps => ps.prudct)
    public productStashes?: Relation<ProductStash[]>;
    
}
```

Join table :

```js
@Entity('product_stash')
export class ProductStash {
    @Column("integer")
    @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'ingredientId' })
    ingredientId?: number;

    @Column("integer")
    @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'stashId' })
    stashId?: number;

    @Column("integer", { default: 1 })
    quantity?: number;

    @Column("text")
    expirationDate!: Date;

    @ManyToOne(type => Product, p => p.productStashes)
    product?: Relation<Product>

    @ManyToOne(type => Stash, s => s.productStashes)
    stash?: Relation<Stash>;
}
```

Now when i try to query a stash and all it's products i get  :

```js
    repository.createQueryBuilder("s")
      .innerJoinAndSelect("s.productStashes", "sp")
      .innerJoinAndSelect("sp.product", "p")
      .where("s.id = :id", { id: stashId })
      .getOne();
```

I get :

```json
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"stash_1",
   "productStashes":[
      {
         "quantity":1,
         "expirationDate":"2023-07-11",
         "product":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"Computer"
         }
      },
      {
         "quantity":1,
         "expirationDate":"2023-07-11 19:06:58.861",
         "product":{
            "id":2,
            "name":"Mouse"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

But what i want is for the extra columns in the join table (expirationDate, quantity) to be in the product object, or maybe just flatten the product object to get something like this :

```json
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"stash_1",
   "productStashes":[
      {
         "quantity":1,
         "expirationDate":"2023-07-11",
         "id":1,
         "name":"Computer"
      },
      {
         "quantity":1,
         "expirationDate":"2023-07-11 19:06:58.861",
         "id":2,
         "name":"Mouse"
      }
   ]
}
```

Any idea on how i can do it ?

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the desired result where the extra columns from the join table (`expirationDate` and `quantity`) are included in the `Product` objects or the `Product` objects are flattened within the `Stash` object, you can modify your query and entity definitions accordingly. Here's how you can do it:

1. Modify your `Stash` entity to include a property for `productStashes` as an array of objects that contain both the `Product` properties and the join table properties.

   @Entity('stash')
   export class Stash {
   @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
   id?: number;

   ```
    @Column("text")
    name!: string;

    @OneToMany(type => ProductStash, ps => ps.stash, { eager: true })
    productStashes?: ProductStash[]; // Use eager loading to load related entities
   ```

   }
2. Modify your query to fetch the required columns from the join table and product, and then format the result as desired:

   const stash = await repository.createQueryBuilder("s")
   .leftJoin("s.productStashes", "ps") // Use left join to include all stashes, even those with no product stashes
   .leftJoin("ps.product", "p")
   .where("s.id = :id", { id: stashId })
   .getOne();

   // Format the result as desired
   const formattedStash = {
   id: stash.id,
   name: stash.name,
   productStashes: stash.productStashes.map(ps => ({
   quantity: ps.quantity,
   expirationDate: ps.expirationDate,
   ...ps.product, // Spread the Product properties
   })),
   };

   console.log(formattedStash);

This code will retrieve the stash and its associated product stashes, including the extra columns (`expirationDate` and `quantity`) from the join table, and then format the result as you specified.

Comment: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)